# Converting & Formating JSON to CSV Correctly?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a JSON URL I want to convert to a CSV file. How can I do this with Python?

I tried:

```
import requests
import csv

params = {
  "format": "csv"
  }
r = requests.get('https://myaccount.srpnet.com/myaccountapi/api/outages/getall', params=params)
print(r.text)

# This bit of code will write the result of the query to output.csv

with open('C:/test/filename.csv', 'w+') as f:
    fieldnames = ["latitude"], ["longitude"]
    f.write(r.text)
```

The output .csv looks like this:

```
"[{""latitude"":33.6031326225"  longitude:-112.193951324    numberCustomersAffected:1   "outageProblem:""An underground power cable has failed. SRP crews are working to restore power."""  isMaintenanceOutage:false   estimatedUsersImpacted:0    "crossRoadText:""N 67TH AVE to N 59TH AVE and W THUNDERBIRD RD to W CACTUS RD"""    "estimatedRestorationTime:""2019-12-16T21:35:00Z""" "outageBegan:""2019-12-16T15:33:27Z"""  "outageId:""486858""}"  "{""latitude"":33.279829655"    longitude:-111.772819298    numberCustomersAffected:1   "outageProblem:""An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible."""  isMaintenanceOutage:true    estimatedUsersImpacted:0    "crossRoadText:""S GILBERT RD to S QUARTZ ST and E PECOS RD to E GERMANN RD"""  "estimatedRestorationTime:""2019-12-16T23:00:00Z""" "outageBegan:""2019-12-16T14:59:11Z"""  "outageId:""486875""}"  "{""latitude"":33.4974939093"   longitude:-111.984698683    numberCustomersAffected:16  "outageProblem:""An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible."""  isMaintenanceOutage:true    estimatedUsersImpacted:0    "crossRoadText:""N 44TH ST to N 48TH ST and E CAMPBELL AVE to E INDIAN SCHOOL RD""" "estimatedRestorationTime:""2019-12-16T21:50:00Z""" "outageBegan:""2019-12-16T15:48:35Z"""  "outageId:""486882""}"  "{""latitude"":33.377234657"    longitude:-111.644471686    numberCustomersAffected:11  "outageProblem:""We continue to investigate the cause."""   isMaintenanceOutage:false   estimatedUsersImpacted:0    "crossRoadText:""S HAWES RD to S ELLSWORTH RD and E BASELINE RD to E STEVEN POLLARD AVE"""  "estimatedRestorationTime:""2019-12-16T20:40:00Z""" "outageBegan:""2019-12-16T18:35:56Z"""  "outageId:""486922""}"  "{""latitude"":33.1435118621"   longitude:-111.521769468    numberCustomersAffected:12  "outageProblem:""An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible."""  isMaintenanceOutage:true    estimatedUsersImpacted:0    "crossRoadText:""N TOURMALINE DR to N SIERRA VISTA RD and E JUDD RD to W SILVERDALE RD"""   "estimatedRestorationTime:""2019-12-16T20:50:00Z""" "outageBegan:""2019-12-16T18:49:03Z"""  "outageId:""486924""}]"
```

What I want it to look like this:

```
latitude    longitude   numberCustomersAffected outageProblem   isMaintenanceOutage estimatedUsersImpacted  crossRoadText   estimatedRestorationTime    outageBegan outageId
33.60313262 -112.1939513    1   An underground power cable has failed. SRP crews are working to restore power.  FALSE   0   N 67TH AVE to N 59TH AVE and W THUNDERBIRD RD to W CACTUS RD    2019-12-16T21:35:00Z    2019-12-16T15:33:27Z    486858
33.50462573 -111.9944968    7   An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   N 36TH ST to N 44TH ST and E CAMELBACK RD to E CAMPBELL AVE 2019-12-16T19:45:00Z    2019-12-16T14:41:08Z    486872
33.41878816 -111.6283175    2   An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   N ELLSWORTH RD to N 96TH ST and E UNIVERSITY DR to E APACHE TRL 2019-12-16T16:45:00Z    2019-12-16T14:44:38Z    486873
33.51363707 -112.0268558    6   An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   N 24TH ST to N 28TH ST and E MISSOURI AVE to E CAMELBACK RD 2019-12-16T16:55:00Z    2019-12-16T14:53:49Z    486874
33.27982966 -111.7728193    1   An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   S GILBERT RD to S QUARTZ ST and E PECOS RD to E GERMANN RD  2019-12-16T23:00:00Z    2019-12-16T14:59:11Z    486875
33.44074458 -112.1861484    0   An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   S 63RD AVE to S 55TH AVE and W VAN BUREN ST to W BUCKEYE RD 2019-12-16T18:05:00Z    2019-12-16T15:02:40Z    486876
33.41773662 -111.9926656    0   An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   S 40TH ST to S 43RD WAY and E UNIVERSITY DR to E ELWOOD ST  2019-12-16T19:30:00Z    2019-12-16T15:26:58Z    486879
33.33877131 -111.7891725    2   An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   S 132ND ST to S LINDSAY RD and W HACKAMORE AVE to E WARNER RD   2019-12-16T16:40:00Z    2019-12-16T15:35:35Z    486880
33.49749391 -111.9846987    16  An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   N 44TH ST to N 48TH ST and E CAMPBELL AVE to E INDIAN SCHOOL RD 2019-12-16T21:50:00Z    2019-12-16T15:48:35Z    486882
33.40325351 -111.8665199    12  An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   S DOBSON RD to S ALMA SCHOOL RD and W BROADWAY RD to W 8TH AVE  2019-12-16T20:45:00Z    2019-12-16T15:41:30Z    486883
33.5133441  -112.1491916    11  An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   GRAND AVE to N 39TH AVE and W MISSOURI AVE to W CAMELBACK RD    2019-12-16T18:45:00Z    2019-12-16T15:44:40Z    486884
33.50472637 -111.9348527    14  An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   N INVERGORDON RD to N SCOTTSDALE RD and E CHAPARRAL RD to E CAMELBACK RD    2019-12-16T17:50:00Z    2019-12-16T15:49:44Z    486886
33.51471289 -112.2795876    7   An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.  TRUE    0   N 107TH AVE to N 99TH AVE and W BETHANY HOME RD to W CAMELBACK RD   2019-12-16T18:55:00Z    2019-12-16T15:52:04Z    486887
```

The JSON API Request looks as follows:

```
[{"latitude":33.6031326225,"longitude":-112.193951324,"numberCustomersAffected":1,"outageProblem":"An underground power cable has failed. SRP crews are working to restore power.","isMaintenanceOutage":false,"estimatedUsersImpacted":0,"crossRoadText":"N 67TH AVE to N 59TH AVE and W THUNDERBIRD RD to W CACTUS RD","estimatedRestorationTime":"2019-12-16T21:35:00Z","outageBegan":"2019-12-16T15:33:27Z","outageId":"486858"},{"latitude":33.279829655,"longitude":-111.772819298,"numberCustomersAffected":1,"outageProblem":"An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.","isMaintenanceOutage":true,"estimatedUsersImpacted":0,"crossRoadText":"S GILBERT RD to S QUARTZ ST and E PECOS RD to E GERMANN RD","estimatedRestorationTime":"2019-12-16T23:00:00Z","outageBegan":"2019-12-16T14:59:11Z","outageId":"486875"},{"latitude":33.4974939093,"longitude":-111.984698683,"numberCustomersAffected":16,"outageProblem":"An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.","isMaintenanceOutage":true,"estimatedUsersImpacted":0,"crossRoadText":"N 44TH ST to N 48TH ST and E CAMPBELL AVE to E INDIAN SCHOOL RD","estimatedRestorationTime":"2019-12-16T21:50:00Z","outageBegan":"2019-12-16T15:48:35Z","outageId":"486882"},{"latitude":33.377234657,"longitude":-111.644471686,"numberCustomersAffected":11,"outageProblem":"We are investigating the cause of the outage.","isMaintenanceOutage":false,"estimatedUsersImpacted":0,"crossRoadText":"S HAWES RD to S ELLSWORTH RD and E BASELINE RD to E STEVEN POLLARD AVE","estimatedRestorationTime":"2019-12-16T20:40:00Z","outageBegan":"2019-12-16T18:35:56Z","outageId":"486922"},{"latitude":33.1435118621,"longitude":-111.521769468,"numberCustomersAffected":12,"outageProblem":"An SRP maintenance crew is performing critical maintenance work to repair or upgrade equipment. Power will be restored as quickly as possible.","isMaintenanceOutage":true,"estimatedUsersImpacted":0,"crossRoadText":"N TOURMALINE DR to N SIERRA VISTA RD and E JUDD RD to W SILVERDALE RD","estimatedRestorationTime":"2019-12-16T20:50:00Z","outageBegan":"2019-12-16T18:49:03Z","outageId":"486924"}]
```

Comment: Please share the data as text in the post itself, not as images. It would also be good to have some reference for what the JSON looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with pandas as following:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas

r = requests.get('https://myaccount.srpnet.com/myaccountapi/api/outages/getall')
data = r.json()
pandas.read_json(json.dumps(data)).to_csv('pandas.csv')
```

Comment: That will do it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your incorrect formated CSV, I guess that `r.text` contains a list of dicts.
So you have first to write the header row, then loop over all rows, and write the data row-by-row. Try something like this:

```
with open('C:/test/filename.csv', 'w+') as f:

    fieldnames = ["latitude", "longitude"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)    
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in r.text:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write out the file using the `csv` module. In particular you need a `DictWriter` instance.

In addition it appears you're getting JSON back from the server. So you need the `json` module to parse that.

Below is a tested code sample.

```
import json, requests

params = {
  "format": "csv"
  }
r = requests.get('https://myaccount.srpnet.com/myaccountapi/api/outages/getall', 
                 params=params)

output = json.loads(r.text)
fieldnames = output[0].keys()

with open('C:/test/filename.csv', 'w+') as f:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames)
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerows(output)
```